# BAT file for silent VPN connect on boot

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, vpn

Just wondering if someone can help me with the following.

I want to auto connect to VPN connection on Windows 7 machine when I boot.

Seen that RASDIAL.EXE is referenced: RASDIAL: rasdial entryname [username [password|*]] [/DOMAIN:domain]

Can someone assist me in what I need to do to create this i.e. do I create this in notepad and is there anything else I need to create and what extension should I save this as?

What steps do I need to do next so that this starts on boot in Windwos 7 and is started silently?

Note: since writing the above I have learn't that RASDIAL.EXE leave me open for username/password being discovered and that I should drag the connection into the startup  of Windows 7 or create a schedule. Again is this is more advisable then I would appreciate some assistance in doing such a thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using the new Direct Access feature of Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2.  When configured it'll setup the client machines to automatically connect to the internal network without prompting the user so that AV can update, GPOs can be downloaded, other internal resources can be accessed without the user needing to start the VPN session.

You will need to use Windows 2008 R2 and have IPv6 enabled within your network to make this work.

Comment: +1 - Worth noting this requires Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, but it really does work very well and is a good step towards a more global IPv6 rollout.

Comment: Updated accordingly.